# Functional analysis on applied math

Tags: functional-analysis, applications, research

I've reading a little bit about applied functional analysis and get a lot of information about its relation with existence and uniqueness of solutions of equations, for instance, equivalence of equations, etc.

However, I do not find yet a direction about the following question: ***It seems to me that today all the results of FAnalysis that are applied are "already done" or about PDE/ODE's. I mean, the theorical results about spaces, etc., are they applied today? Seems the modern research in FAnalysis is applied only on PDE/ODE's. Is it true?***

I mean, there is some subject of research that uses, today, theorical FAnalysis and applied math? Particularly interested on ***biomathemathics, oxigenation***, or something similar.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=YcGVAcWVLHwC&pg=PA439&lpg=PA439&dq=%22Functional+analysis+in+general+and+wavelet+methods+in+particular+provide+basic+tools+to+make+systematic+analysis+of+problems+related+to+signals+and%22&source=bl&ots=KTlP62349n&sig=ACfU3U1kuL6stRcfzQrVlvkx1VajvhaLsQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKk5OStpjmAhWCJ7kGHUx8B9EQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Functional%20analysis%20in%20general%20and%20wavelet%20methods%20in%20particular%20provide%20basic%20tools%20to%20make%20systematic%20analysis%20of%20problems%20related%20to%20signals%20and%22&f=false) can be of interest.

Comment: Yes, thank you, Pedro!

Comment: Functional analysis also has connections to knot theory and Topological Quantum Computation . . .